# In which time zone does the openshift server operates by default?

Tags: java, timezone, openshift, scheduled-tasks

I am scheduling my cron job for `0 0 22 * * ?`. Is it going to get executed at 10 pm CST?

Comment: **`0 22 * * *`**

Answer (score 1):

In general, this will depend on your Master Nodes:

> All CronJob schedule: times are based on the timezone of the kube-controller-manager .

Source: https://v1-17.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/

So it will depend on your specific configuration of your cluster, often Master nodes are running with the **UTC** timezone, but they may also be configured to use your **local timezone**.